# Не подключается js скрипт

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars

Не подключается js скрип к сайту, выдает ошибку net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). Пробовал сделать папку статической с помощью

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Но ошибка никуда не пропала. Пытаюсь подключить **reglog.js**

**Весь проект**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.hbs**

```html
{{> head}}
<body>
<header>
    {{> navbar}}
</header>
    {{{ body }}}
</body>
<div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="public/reglog.js"></script>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании express static доступ к директории public осуществляется через корень сайта, то есть надо не `public/reglog.js`, а просто `reglog.js`.

```
<script src="reglog.js"></script>
```